# how to convert string into dictionary in python 3.*?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to convert the following string into dictionary without using `eval()` function in Python 3.5.

```py
d="{'Age': 7, 'Name': 'Manni'}";
```

Can anybody tell me the good way than using the `eval()` function?

What I *really* want is a function which can directly convert a dictionary to a string.

Comment: this question is about python 3 , and is marked as an duplicated of python 2 don't agree

Comment: I don't think this should be marked duplicate.

Answer (score 86):

1. `literal_eval`, a somewhat safer version of `eval` (will only evaluate literals ie strings, lists etc):

   ```
   from ast import literal_eval

   python_dict = literal_eval("{'a': 1}")
   ```
2. `json.loads` but it would require your string to use double quotes:

   ```
   import json

   python_dict = json.loads('{"a": 1}')
   ```

Comment: I was getting crazy on why `json.loads()` was not working for me. **Thanks** for that clarification.

Comment: @DeepSpace can you tell why it's safer? I've noticed that it's quite CPU expensive as solution

Comment: @Olfredos6 It has nothing to do with CPU usage. `eval` is simply unsafe, especially when used with uncontrolled user input. See what happens if you execute `import os ; eval("os.remove('do_not_replace_with_a_valid_path')")`. On the other-hand, `literal_eval` will only work with, well, literals. `literal_eval("os.remove('do_not_replace_with_a_valid_path')")` outputs `ValueError: malformed node or string`

Comment: @DeepSpace alright...