# How to get value in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe column, one row contain data:

```
bloodtype
[{'id': 35, 
  'type': 'typeO'}]
```

The column contain different blood type, A,B,AB, and O in other rows.

I ran:

```
type(df.blood_type)
```

it returned `'pandas.core.series.Series'`

```
df['blood_type'].str.split(":")[0][2]
```

it return   `" 'typeO'}]"`

How can I just get `typeO, typeA, typeAB` so i could convert them different classes. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to substring a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
from ast import literal_eval
df['type'] = df['blood_type'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x[0]).type)
```

Alternate solution:

```
#a more robust solution to incase the series has unexpected values
def extract_type(x):
     try:
         if type(literal_eval(x)) == 'dict':
             return literal_eval(x)
         else:
             return None
     except ValueError:
         return None

df['type'] = df['blood_type'].apply(extract_type)
```

edit: convert string representation of dict to dictionary using ast.literal_eval before extracting type

Comment: Thanks but I got error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'type'

Comment: just updated the answer to [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694800/how-to-convert-string-into-dictionary-in-python-3/38694850) string representation of dict before extracting type.